# I am trying to add DataTemplate XAML code dynamically for CarouselView from View Model in MAUI. I am getting error. Please refer the attached images

Tags: xamarin.forms, maui, .net-maui, maui-windows, maui-community-toolkit

Refer the below code snippets,

I am having Frame observable collection in View Model and it is binding to the UI.

In UI, I have CarouselView and assigning the DataTemplate values with ViewModel Property.

```
   **ViewModel Property:**

  public ObservableCollection<Frame> CarouselViewItemSource
    {
        get => carouselViewItemSource;
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref carouselViewItemSource, value);

        }
    }
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please do not post code as images

Comment: I suggest look at stacktrace when that exception is thrown. I think it shows some traces related to your code. My guess is the first line in the try-catch, but see it yourself first.